# Advent of code #2 Haskell solution

Tags: haskell

I've tried to solve AoC day 2 challenge in Haskell ([here](https://adventofcode.com/2019/day/2) - don't worry, it's not a competition so sharing a solution here is OK).

The goal is to implement a very simple VM with opcodes 1 (add), 2 (mult) and 99 (exit).

I feel like my solution is incredibly verbose. That maybe be because I rely heavily on the state monad (my background is imperative programming, so there's that). Is there anything I could improve without rewriting the whole solution?

Here's my code, thanks for all suggestions:

````hs
import Data.Sequence
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.List.Split

data Machine = Machine {
    mState :: Seq Int,
    mPos :: Int,
    isDone :: Bool
}

opReadHead :: State Machine Int
opReadHead = do
    machine <- get
    return $ index (mState machine) (mPos machine)

opReadAt :: Int -> State Machine Int
opReadAt target = do
    machine <- get
    return $ index (mState machine) target

opForward :: State Machine ()
opForward = do
    machine <- get
    put $ machine { mPos = mPos machine + 1 }

opWrite :: Int -> Int -> State Machine ()
opWrite target what = do
    machine <- get
    put $ machine { mState = update target what (mState machine) }

opReadNext :: State Machine Int
opReadNext = do
    a <- opReadHead
    opForward
    return a

opAdd :: State Machine ()
opAdd = do
    aPtr <- opReadNext
    a <- opReadAt aPtr
    bPtr <- opReadNext
    b <- opReadAt bPtr
    target <- opReadNext
    opWrite target (a + b)

opMult :: State Machine ()
opMult = do
    aPtr <- opReadNext
    a <- opReadAt aPtr
    bPtr <- opReadNext
    b <- opReadAt bPtr
    target <- opReadNext
    opWrite target (a * b)

opExit :: State Machine ()
opExit = do
    current <- get
    put $ current { isDone = True }

isMachineDone :: State Machine Bool
isMachineDone = do
    get >>= (return . isDone)

opcode :: Int -> State Machine ()
opcode 1 = opAdd
opcode 2 = opMult
opcode 99 = opExit

opExecuteNext :: State Machine ()
opExecuteNext = do
    opValue <- opReadNext
    opcode opValue

runCode :: State Machine ()
runCode = do
    done <- isMachineDone
    if done
    then return ()
    else opExecuteNext >> runCode 

evalWith :: Machine -> Int -> Int -> Int
evalWith machine noun verb = do
    fst $ runState (do
        opWrite 1 noun
        opWrite 2 verb
        runCode
        opReadAt 0
        ) machine

main :: IO()
main = do
    fileData <- readFile "input"
    let memory = map read $ splitOn "," fileData
    let machine = Machine {
        mState = fromList memory,
        mPos = 0,
        isDone = False
    }
    let outputs = [(evalWith machine x y, (x, y)) | x <- [0..99], y <- [0..99]]
    print $ snd $ head $ Prelude.filter ((== 19690720) . fst) outputs
```
````

Answer (score 4):

Use `Control.Lens` for code this stateful. (`Control.Lens.TH` must be used to define `Machine`.) May as well leave out type signatures this homogenous. `Control.Monad.Loops` often helps against explicit monadic recursion.

```
opReadAt target = uses mState $ (`index` target)
opReadNext = mPos <<+= 1 >>= opReadAt
opWrite target what = mState %= update target what

opBin op = do
    a <- opReadNext >>= opReadAt
    b <- opReadNext >>= opReadAt
    target <- opReadNext
    opWrite target $ op a b 

opcode 1 = opBin (+)
opcode 2 = opBin (*)
opcode 99 = isDone .= True

runCode = (opReadNext >>= opCode) `untilM_` use isDone

evalWith :: Int -> Int -> Machine -> Int
evalWith noun verb = evalState $ do
    opWrite 1 noun
    opWrite 2 verb
    runCode
    opReadAt 0
```

Comment: I'm very curious how you could improve it using a Lens but the documentation for that is very useless for somebody new. Could you given an example of how it would work?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for this, I used your example to finish mine that also uses `State`:

```hs
import System.IO
import Data.Sequence
import Control.Monad.State
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Data.Maybe

convertToInteger :: String -> Int
convertToInteger s = read s :: Int

type CompState = (Int, Seq Int)
type CompValue = Int

data Instruction = Add | Mult | Stop deriving (Show)

instruction :: State CompState Instruction
instruction = state $ \(pointer, mem) ->
    (case (Data.Sequence.lookup pointer mem) of
        Just 1 -> Add
        Just 2 -> Mult
        Just 99 -> Stop
        _ -> Stop
    , (pointer, mem))

calcul :: (Int -> Int -> Int) -> State CompState ()
calcul operator = state $ \(pointer, mem) ->
    let addr1 = Data.Sequence.lookup (pointer+1) mem
        addr2 = Data.Sequence.lookup (pointer+2) mem
        op1 = join $ Data.Sequence.lookup <$> addr1 <*> pure mem
        op2 = join $ Data.Sequence.lookup <$> addr2 <*> pure mem
        destAddr = Data.Sequence.lookup (pointer+3) mem 
        val = (operator <$> op1 <*> op2)
        newMem = Data.Sequence.update <$> destAddr <*> val <*> pure mem in
    ((), (pointer+4, fromJust newMem))

computeStep :: State CompState ()
computeStep = do
    inst <- instruction

    _ <- case inst of
        Add -> calcul (+) >> computeStep
        Mult -> calcul (*) >> computeStep
        Stop -> return ()

    return ()

a = [1,0,0,0,99]
b = [2,3,0,3,99]
c = [2,4,4,5,99,0]   
d = [1,1,1,4,99,5,6,0,99]

main :: IO()
main = do
    handle <- openFile "2-input.txt" ReadMode
    contents <- hGetContents handle

    let inputData = fromList . map convertToInteger . map T.unpack $ T.splitOn (T.pack ",") (T.pack contents)
    let updatedInputData = update 2 2 (update 1 12 inputData)

    print $ snd $ snd $ runState computeStep (0, updatedInputData)
```

Is it shorter or does it only look like it?

Comment: `instruction` should be written in terms of `gets`. `calcul` in terms of `modify`. `Instruction` is superfluous. So's the `Just 99` case. Don't use `Maybe` if you're merely gonna `fromJust`. `snd $ runState` -> `evalState`.

Comment: Thanks for your additions which are barely understandable since I could only just get this State thing to work (almost no documentation) and have after this experience moved on from Haskell.