# Advent of Code 2 - Intcode Interpreter in Haskell

Tags: haskell

### Problem

The problem definition is [here](https://adventofcode.com/2019/day/2). For a quick summary:

- an IntCode program is an array of ints
- the program counter starts from index 0, where it reads an opcode, followed by 0 or more arguments at the next indices, then proceeds to the index after the last argument
- opcode 1 takes 3 arguments, `a`, `b`, and `z`, and sets `program[z] = program[a] + program[b]`
- opcode 2 does the same but multiplies instead
- opcode 99 takes 0 arguments and halts the program

In part 1, we take [the input](https://adventofcode.com/2019/day/2/input), replace index 1 with 12 and index 2 with 2 (`restore 12 2`), run the program and return index 0.

In part 2 (not shown in the link unless you solve part 1), we find which ints to replace index 1 and 2 with to produce a result where index 0 equals 19690720.

---

My thoughts on this code are that it could probably be simpler. I tried to separate the program counter logic from the instruction execution logic (`interpret` vs `step`), but it seems like that resulted in the need for a strange combinator `whileWith`. I was wondering whether there are better combinators to express this kind of loop, or if there's another approach entirely.

I considered wrapping `step` in `ContT` or `ExceptT`, which would allow some of the nesting to be flattened by using early exit instead, but I wasn't sure which way is best in terms of extensibility.

Any suggestions on this code are welcome, including style, structure, algorithm, etc!

### Code

```hs
import Control.Arrow (second)
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Array
import Data.Array.ST
import Data.List (find)

data Status = InvalidOp | Terminated | Running | InvalidAddress
  deriving (Show, Eq)

newtype Program = Program {
  getInts :: Array Int Int
} deriving (Show)

-- Execute the instruction starting at `start`
step :: STArray s Int Int -> Int -> Int -> ST s Status
step arr len start = do
  op <- readArray arr start
  case op of
    99 -> return Terminated
    _ -> do
      [i, j, store] <- forM [start+1..start+3] (readArray arr)
      if not $ all inBounds [i, j, store] then
        return InvalidAddress
      else do
        [a, b] <- forM [i, j] (readArray arr)
        case op of
          1 -> writeArray arr store (a+b) >> return Running
          2 -> writeArray arr store (a*b) >> return Running
          _ -> return InvalidOp

  where inBounds ix = 0 <= ix && ix < len

interpret :: Program -> Program
interpret (Program prog) = Program $ runSTArray $ do
  let len = succ . uncurry subtract $ bounds prog
  mArr <- thaw prog
  whileWith (== Running) [0, 4..len-1]
    (step mArr len)
  return mArr

readProgram :: String -> Program
readProgram str =
  let nums = fmap read $ split ',' str
  in
  Program $ listArray (0, length nums - 1) nums

restore :: Int -> Int -> Program -> Program
restore a b = Program . (// [(1, a), (2, b)]) . getInts

-- pt 2

findNounVerb :: Program -> Int -> Maybe (Int, Int)
findNounVerb prog target =
  find ((== target) . (! 0) . getInts . interpret . ($ prog) . uncurry restore) $
      [(n, v) | n <- [0..1000], v <- [0..n]]

-- util --

split :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [[a]]
split _ [] = []
split k xs = curr : split k rest
  where (curr, rest) = second (drop 1) $ span (/= k) xs

whileWith :: (Monad m) => (ret -> Bool) -> [inp] -> (inp -> m ret) -> m ()
whileWith _ [] _ = return ()
whileWith pred (x:xs) step = do
  res <- step x
  when (pred res) $
    whileWith pred xs step

-- end util --

main :: IO ()
main = do
  prog <- readProgram <$> getContents

  -- pt 1:
  putStrLn "Part 1:"
  let output = (! 0) . getInts . interpret . restore 12 2 $ prog
  putStrLn $ "Output: " ++ show output
  putStrLn ""

  -- pt 2:
  putStrLn "Part 2:"
  let Just (noun, verb) = findNounVerb prog 19690720
  putStrLn $ "Noun: " ++ show noun ++ "\n" ++ "Verb: " ++ show verb
  print $ 100*noun + verb
```

Comment: Compare https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/233696/advent-of-code-2-haskell-solution